# Multiple unity3d assetbundle download in a single progress bar?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, progress-bar, assetbundle

I'm trying to make a single download progress bar for multiple assetbundle. The total size of all the assetbundle was computed by adding its `webRequest.GetResponseHeader("Content-Length")`. But the `www.downloadProgress` returns a value from 0 to 1 only.

Here's the sample code:

```
float progress = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < assetToDownload.Count; i++)
{
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.GetAssetBundle(assetToDownload[i], 0, 0);
    www.Send();

    while (!www.isDone)
    {
        progress += www.downloadProgress * 100;
        Debug.Log((progress / totalSize) * 100);
        yield return null;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not make it yourself so hard by getting the content-size with a diffrent request. You just need to use the 0-1 values from unity and add them together. This won't make a diffrence when viewing it from a progressbar and isn't such a pain in the a** to implement. 
I hope this helps.

```
//To calculate the percantage
float maxProgress = assetToDownload.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < assetToDownload.Count; i++)
{
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.GetAssetBundle(assetToDownload[i], 0, 0);
    www.Send();

    //To remember the last progress
    float lastProgress = progress;
    while (!www.isDone)
    {
        //Calculate the current progress
        progress = lastProgress + www.downloadProgress;
        //Get a percentage
        float progressPercentage = (progress / maxProgress) * 100;
    }
}
```